# Setting class attributes/properties from a dict holding properties

Tags: python, object

I have a class with some attributes/properties that are to be set at init by reading a dictionary with str as key and item. These values are going to be turned into class properties/attributes. so I have something like this:

```
class Attendee:
    def __init__(self, attendee):
        # creating a small example attendee dict here:
        self.attendee = {"email": "someone@somewhere.com", "id": "1234"}
        self._email = None
        self._id = None

        self.init_attribute = {"email": self.email, "id": self.id}

        self.init_attributes()

    def init_attributes(self):
        for k in self.attendee.keys():
            self.init_attribute[k] = self.attendee[k]

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, value):
        self._email = value

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self._id = value
```

The idea is that using the dict self.init_attribute is going to save me a lot of lines of code. However, this does not work. All attributes are still None after init. Thus, `self.init_attribute[k] = self.attendee[k]` does not manage to set the attributes when called like this. Can anyone explain to me why this is not working, and a possible solution?

Comment: You are setting the attributes to None (`self._email = None`)

Comment: yes, but that is fine @DaniMesejo. Then self.init_attributes is called, which is supposed to read through self.attendees and set the attributes if the exist.

Comment: How is self.init_attributes going to the set email for example? Where do you do self._email = x inside self.init_attributes?

Comment: it is called from self.init_attribute[k] = self.attendee[k]

Comment: Thats the issue that does nothing related to what you want, it basically only sets a dictionary init_attribute ...

Comment: @DaniMesejo that I do not quite understand. The dictionary holdes the global properties (self.email and self.id in this example) with their setters... so when `k = "email"`  self.init_attribute[k] should give self.email and self.attendee[k] will give "someone@somewhere.com".  The results I was hoping for here was that this sholud become self.email = "someone@somewhere.com" ... calling the property setter from a dictionary. This works for functions, why not here?

Comment: It does not holds the properties is holds the values, when you do self.email is like calling a function self.email() that returns the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `init_attributes` is not setting the attributes of your class. One approach is to use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
def init_attributes(self):
    for k, v in self.attendee.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

then it can be done as follows:

```
att = Attendee(None)
print(att.email)
```

**Output**

```
someone@somewhere.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was exactly what I needed - and I learned something new. This was brilliant!

Comment: @GeirVilly Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

you dont need setter functions . please try the below solution

```
class Attendee:
    def __init__(self, attendee):
        # creating a small example attendee dict here:
        self.attendee = attendee
        self._email = self.attendee['email']
        self._id = self.attendee['id']

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, value):
        self._email = value

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self._id = value
a = Attendee({"email": "someone@somewhere.com", "id": "1234"})
print(a.email)
print(a.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is exactly what I am trying to avoid doing. In the real code, the self.attendee can be huge, and I do not want to code each of the keys explicitly. But, sure, this works, I know.

Answer (score 0):

So the fundamental problem here is that you're never *actually* setting the value of the properties to anything; in `init_attributes`, you're just setting the value of a given key to the value that that key has in a different dict, but this is never actually assigned to the attribute.

To achieve what you're trying to do, you could us the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module as follows to deconstruct your dict and assign it directly to the relevant attributes:

```
from operator import itemgetter

class Attendee:
def __init__(self, attendee):
    # creating a small example attendee dict here:
    self.attendee = {"email": "someone@somewhere.com", "id": "1234"}
    self._email, self._id = itemgetter('email', 'id')(self.attendee)
```